# Django select_related does nothing

Tags: python, django

I have a comment model in django which contains a foreign key reference to the User model and I'm trying to lookup comments (of a certain post ID) and then join/get the user data of the author of the commment. This is what I'm doing

```
    result = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).select_related('user').order_by('-created_at')
```

When I return the result, I get the same exact object I got before I added the `select_related()` function. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What did you expect to be different?

Comment: @willemvanonsem Shouldn't I see the user data in the object like a regular join? I just see the user ID.

Comment: no, the idea of `.select_related` is that it will make a `JOIN` and thus load the data in the related `.user` object in the same query. You thus avoid an *N+1 problem*.

Comment: @willemvanonsem Yes this is exactly what I want but like I said it doesnt get the user data

Comment: well you access it with for example `mycomment.user.username` (to objtain the username of the author (I assume)).

Comment: @ninesalt and how are you trying to display the user data? What makes you think it doesn't get the user data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) function makes a JOIN in the query, and thus will use the query to load the data of the related `.user` object. If you do *not* use `.select_related(…)`, then accessing `.user` of a `Comment` will result in an extra query. If you thus need to load all the users of *N* `Comment`s, then that will take *N+1* queries (and this is the famous *N+1* problem).

`.select_related(…)` thus *functionally* does not change (much), it however results in a (significant) performance boost if you plan to access all the `.user`s of the `Comment`s.

You thus can for example print the `.username` of the `.user`s in the `Comment` objects with:

```
for comment in Comment.objects.select_related('user'):
    print(comment.user.username)
```

If you do this *without* a `.select_related(…)` clause, it will result in a large amount of queries.

Comment: Okay so I think I get what I did wrong. I was using a serializer (DRF) for the Comment model that didnt have a nested serializer for the user data so I added it. Not sure if that's the right way but it seems to be working